# Property 'interval' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, angular

**My objective:**

> I want to create a timer application which prompts a user to enter
>   time in seconds and the application will count down to the specified
>   time entered (it’s a countdown timer: you enter time in seconds,
>   application counts down from your entered value to zero )

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeWhile';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';


const interval = Observable.interval(100);
           interval
            .takeWhile((_: any) => !this.isFinished )
            .do( () => this.current += 0.1)
            .subscribe();
```

**Version Details:**

- Angular CLI: 8.3.5
- Node: 12.2.0
- rxjs: 6.4.0

**EDIT:**
I'd like to interprate this code:

```
const interval = Observable.interval(100);
               interval
                .takeWhile((_: any) => !this.isFinished )
                .do( () => this.current += 0.1)
                .subscribe();
```

to the latest standard as of **rxjs:6.4.0** , all other things kept constant (*trying to get some lingo but I'm still getting my hands dirty with Angular*)

Comment: See this: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval#example

Comment: You use RxJS 6.4.0 but using methods of older version. See: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html

Answer (score 0):

Rxjs 6 does not want you to use deep imports! You should use the `.pipe` method to chain together operations, who are in turn imported from `rxjs/operators`.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, takeWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';


const interval = interval(100);

let current = 0;
interval.pipe(
  takeWhile((_: any) => current < 5),
  map((_: any) => {current += 0.1; return current; })
).subscribe(
  (value: any) => {
    console.log(value);
    // Do something here while current < 5
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rxjs 6+ you should import operators from `'rxjs/operators'` and Observable functions from `'rxjs'` as said in this [update guide](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths), and operators are now used with `pipe()` as said [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax).

That should do it:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const userValueSeconds = 3;

interval(100).pipe(    // run every 100ms
  takeWhile(i => userValueSeconds - (i/10) >= 0 ),  // stop when it gets to the value entered
  map(i => i * 100)                                  // map to ms
).subscribe(ms => console.log(ms));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/timer-example-333) code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Seconds" [formControl]="secondsCtrl">
<button (click)="run(secondsCtrl.value)">Run</button>
<div> TIMER: {{timer$ | async | date : 'mm:ss:SS'}} </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { takeWhile, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  secondsCtrl: FormControl;
  timer$: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.secondsCtrl = new FormControl(3);
  }

  run(seconds: number) {
    this.timer$ = interval(100).pipe(
      takeWhile(i => seconds - (i/10)  >= 0 ),
      map(i => i * 100)
    );
  }


}
```